# Different type behaviour while using function vs using raw code

Tags: typescript

Is it a bug or I don't understand something? Why does typescript act differently when I try to mutate the function argument via calling the narrowing function and it acts differently when I do the same via raw copy-pasted code?

```js
function castString(value: unknown): string {
  if (typeof value !== "string") {
    throw new Error(`Expected ${value} to be string, got ${typeof value}`);
  }
  return value;
}

function narrowUnknownTostring(rawParam: unknown): void {
  rawParam = castString(rawParam);
  const narrowedParamError: string = rawParam; // Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'

  // Just copy-paste the castString function
  if (typeof rawParam !== "string") {
    throw new Error(`Expected ${rawParam} to be string, got ${typeof rawParam}`);
  }
  const narrowedParamOk: string = rawParam; // Everything's fine
}
```

Comment: You're not "mutating" the argument. `rawParam` is declared as `unknown`, and that's its type. Assigning something else to it doesn't change the type of the variable - it's still `unknown`.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, but on the other hand using `if` seems to change the type of variable.

Comment: Because you're not reassigning it back to an `unknown`.

Comment: What do you expect `x` to be when declared as `let x: unknown;`? It's `unknown`, right? Because that's its type. Having `x = 42; x = "hello";` is still valid code. If your expectation is for one of these assignments to fail, then - why? `x` is `unknown` - both a number and a string are assignable to it. Assignments don't do narrowing. There is just a type check for the assignment for whether it's valid. The type just defines what is valid or not to be assigned to a variable. Type narrowing is a separate mechanic unrelated to assignments.

Comment: > Assignments don't do narrowing.

It seems to not be true.
Check out this example: https://pastecode.io/s/fzj215dr

```typescript
function narrowUnknownTostring(rawParam: string | number): void {
  const narrowedParamError: string = rawParam; // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`
  rawParam = castString(rawParam);`
  const narrowedParamOk: string = rawParam; // Everything's fine`
}
```

Comment: There is effectively constant that I didn't want to get into with comments. The type of the variable is still not changed, however since there are no other reassignments unions are narrowed: https://tsplay.dev/W4OrAm it's still `string | number`, doesn't turn into `string` only. Note that I said *unions*. That's not what `unknown` is.

Comment: "it's still string | number, doesn't turn into string only." - Ok, that's the reasoning I'll try to follow. But still, "Type narrowing is a separate mechanic unrelated to assignments." - it's a bit slippery to me. But thanks for the example it makes things a bit more clear.